# Atom Editor - How to fix: tabs are not replaced by spaces

Tags: python, format, atom-editor

I have recently installed atom in a new computer to write some python code. When I realized I was writing with "hard" tabs, I tried to change them to "soft" tabs (4 spaces instead of a tab character).

In editor settings I changed "auto" tabs by "soft" tabs and I set spaces to 4. After that, the tabs remained "hard". I took a look at the config.cson file:

```
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "no"
  editor:
    tabLength: 4
    tabType: "soft"
```

It looked good but soft tabs did not work. I added the following:

```
".python.source":
  editor:
    tabLength: 4
    tabType: "soft"
```

But nothing.

Does anyone have an idea about what may be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, changing this setting only affects future indentations, it shouldn't reindent your code retroactively. However, you can use select your code and run the **Editor:  Auto Indent** command to achieve that.

Alternatively, there are many [third-party packages](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=format%20python&commit=Search) that might work better for you.